# How to perform two-stage PCA?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis

I was reading [this](https://www.bbvaresearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/WP14-26_Financial-Inclusion1.pdf) paper when I stumbled upon two-staged PCA; apparently it divides indicators into sub-indices because empirical evidence supports that PCA is biased towards the weights of indicators which are highly correlated with each. I was wondering how to make sense of the step by step process and how to perform it in Stata.

Comment: Your reference is a 40-page document. Could you pin down a relevant section/page?

Comment: Looks like a bi-factor model under a different name.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1708041-how-to-perform-two-staged-pca